# Rails - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting the following error when I try to pull up an old app and can't seem to pin point the problem. I'm getting a 'call_with_exception' error and Googling provided no help. Can anyone point me to the right direction? I'm on Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7, and using RVM.

```
$ script/server 
=> Booting Mongrel
=> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
  SQL (0.1ms)   SET SQL_AUTO_IS_NULL=0
/!\ FAILSAFE /!\  Tue May 24 08:31:57 -0700 2011
  Status: 500 Internal Server Error
  undefined method `call_with_exception' for ApplicationController:Class
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:90:in `dispatch'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:121:in `_call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:130:in `build_middleware_stack'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/activerecord-2.3.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/string_coercion.rb:25:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:114:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:34:in `run'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/actionpack-2.3.5/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:108:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:64:in `process'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rack-1.0.1/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p334@rails235/gems/rails-2.3.5/lib/commands/server.rb:111
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `gem_original_require'
    /Users/my_user_dir/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p334/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:29:in `require'
    script/server:3
```

Comment: Could you post your application controller code. It's difficult to help if we don't know where the error is? Does upgrading to rails 2.3.11 help?

Comment: Looks like it was a rogue initializer that was screwing things up.

Comment: Can you answer your own question in a way that would help others? If you do, you can select yours as the correct answer. It may seem strange, but it is the preferred way of dealing with situations like this.

Comment: It's better if you can attach the related code for this kind of questions. It may give some sort of help to understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First, as you may already know, make sure you used the right ruby version

```
rvm list #find the right ruby-1.8.7 version you have used to get this app running back then
```

Then (if for example you used p249)

```
rvm ruby-1.8.7-p249
```

If that does not work, it is a good time to be a bit adventurous and debug rails core. "put" method helps a lot here.

I personally froze my rails into my app first before doing this, and make any changes directly there (not recommended, most of the times I write mix-ins but not all times).

To freeze rails gems:

```
rake gems:unpack
```

then

```
rake gems:install
```